# How add Sign In With Apple plugin Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, sign-in-with-apple

I tried with cordova plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple
```

Whit this implementation code:

```
//before @component add declare var cordova: any;

    async loginWithAppleID() {
    await cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.signin(
      {requestedScopes: [0, 1]},
      (succ) => {
        //get email and full name from Apple ID
        console.log(succ)
        let userData = {
          name: succ.fullName.givenName + ' ' + succ.fullName.familyName,
          email: succ.email,
        };
// this.AuthApi;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
      }
    )
  }
```

And I am facing the error "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.AuthorenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)".

I check the Sign in with Apple capability on Xcode and Apple Developer Console, but still the error is present. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: as per this thread you should test in real device https://github.com/twogate/cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple/issues/27

Comment: I fixed this problem applying this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975122/ionic-4-with-capacitor-xcodebuild-fails-with-manual-signing-process?answertab=votes#tab-top